# Why AlphaVantage doesn't provide recent data

Tags: alpha-vantage

I'm using the API of AlphaVantage.co to get daily stock data. It seems to be nice because it provides exchange rates US, Europe and the world + currency exchange + crypto currency.
Unfortunatly in some cases it turns out that the latest data is one day behind the realtime data from the stock exchange.
Example: Aurora Cannabis: symbol=21P1
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=21P1.FRK&apikey=...
Tested today 10th of July: most recent data point is from 9th of July.
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AKzx.png

Is there any rule why and when AV won't show the latest data?

Appreciate your help,
Moblitz

Comment: _Is there any rule why and when AV won't show the latest data?_ Aren't the people at AlphaVantage the only ones who can really answer that?

Comment: I already addressed this question to support at Alphavantage, but they never directly answered it - maybe I had only contact to the first level support. So I hoped to find here someone with AV experience or maybe an employee from AV will answer this question directly and not via the unpersonal support mail.

Comment: @patrick-collins could you help with this one?